# What does “yo-ho-ho” mean?

Tags: pirate-english

The pirate song “Fifteen Men on a Dead Man’s Chest” from *Treasure Island* contains the expression *yo-ho-ho*.

> Fifteen men on the dead man’s chest—
>   
> *Yo-ho-ho*, and a bottle of rum!
>   
> Drink and the devil had done for the rest—
>   
> *Yo-ho-ho*, and a bottle of rum!

Does this signify laughter, a piratical variation of *ho-ho-ho*? It doesn’t seem like an amusing little ditty but then pirates probably would have a dark sense of humour. Or is it simply a more piratey song filler than *na-na-na*?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Accordin’ to [yon pirate page](http://www.yarr.org.uk/talk/), *yo-ho-ho* indeed be pirate laughter.

But there be also [another source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yo-ho-ho) claimin’ that ’tis merely a scallywag’s variant of *yo-heave-ho*, the chant that all good sea-farin’ folk use to keep their rhythm when haulin’ cannon to the scuppers.

Seems ’tis likely *yo-ho-ho* be used to maintain the rhythm in yer fine sea chantey as well. When ye shipmates sing out *yo*, yer all be givin’ yon rope a hearty pull.

Comment: On the other hand, "yo-oh-no!" means "where has all the rum gone?"

Comment: Hah, this answer is brilliant! :D

Comment: Because I _just have to be that guy_, I must add that "scallywag" or "scalawag" is not a pirate expression at all.  Johnny Depp as Jack Sparrow uses it in the first _Pirates of the Caribbean_ movie, but it's a gross anachronism.  The word was a Reconstruction-Era (1865 to 1877, long after the Golden Age of piracy) term for a white Southerner who allied himself with black freedmen and the carpetbaggers in support of Republican Party policies.  Consider using the word "lubber" instead.

Comment: @malvolio Yargh, that I shall. Many thanks to you.

Answer (score 6):

*Yo-ho-ho* is related to *yoho*, which is in the Oxford Dictionary of English:

> An exclamation used to call attention: orig. in nautical use, hence generally; also sometimes used like yo-heave-ho int., q.v.

It dates from the 1700s:

> 1769    W. Falconer Universal Dict. Marine (1780) 11,   Hola-ho, a cry which answers to yoe-hoe.

*Yo ho ho* may either have been extended to fit in the song, or an alternative version of *yo heave ho* or *yoho*.

Comment: Do you think then it is a hauling shanty, and this signifies the pull?

Comment: @z7sgѪ Aye, t'is.

Comment: So, it's also related to http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yoohoo :)

Answer (score 0):

During the construction of the Canals and railways in England, "Yo-ho, yo-ho" was called to signify the end of a shift.

English Navvies drank prodigious amounts of alcohol at the end of a shift. It would be nice to think that Robert Louis Stevenson made the parallel for Pirates.

Yo-ho and bottle of rum.

Comment: Hello James, can you add some reputable citations to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think james is correct.  In the patrick stewart version of a christmas carol, maybe in the book also, when fezziwig is closing shop, he says " yoho ebinezer, yoho dick", to signal shift is over.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. "Answers" should attempt to answer the question (which you have not quite done), not engage in further discussion. This site is not a forum. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.