# Meaning of "Y-o-u-u Tom!"

Tags: meaning, etymology, american-english, history, literature

In the opening chapter of Twain's [The Adventures of Tom Sawyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Tom_Sawyer), Tom's aunt Polly calls out to him in a rather peculiar fashion:

> She went to the open door and stood in it, and looked out among the tomato vines and "Jimpson" weeds that constituted the garden. No Tom. So she lifted up her voice at an angle calculated for distance and shouted:
>
> **"Y-o-u-u Tom!"**
>
> There was a slight noise behind her and she turned just in time to seize a small boy by the slack of his roundabout and arrest his flight.

What's with this "Y-o-u-u" business? How is it meant to be read? Is it perhaps an antecedent of [yoo-hoo](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/yoo-hoo)?

Comment: No - it's just an attempt to mirror actual speech (well, here, fictitious speech) in the written word. In music, the trombone would play four notes loudly while the singer spread out the  single word _you_. It would be a slide (no pun intended) rather than four separate syllables.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you. And what does "You Tom!" mean? When _y-o-u-u_ is spread out, it begins to sound just like _yoo-hoo_.

Comment: You here is merely a pragmatic marker, subset attention-grabber like HEY! or (non-verbal) blowing a whistle or firing a flare. It may be omitted without rendering the remaining expression ungrammatical. One can probably put more emphasis on you than Tom; You! and certainly Hey, you! are often used as attention-demanders rather than grabbers (and aren't over-polite). There possibly is a connection with yoo-hoo!, but the latter expression has a less incisive, even namby-pamby, flavour. However, M-W says that it is probably a corruption of _yo-ho_, which seems piratical or at least nautical.

Comment: It would be interesting to consider the many movie versions of *Tom Sawyer* and see (in those including this line) how the actress pronounces "Y-o-u-u Tom!"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the answer-as-a-comment-as-an-answer :) I find the use of _you_ as a discourse marker to be odd in the case of "You Tom!". "Yoo-hoo", "hello", "hey", "yo", "ho", "hoy", "ahoy", etc. are/were standard greetings and used as attention-seeking words. So, "H-e-l-l-o Tom!" would fit in perfectly. "You", to my ears, sounds off.

Comment: To your ears it sounds off ... I guess you don't live in Pike County, then.  Or (less likely) Twain got it wrong.

Comment: @GEdgar :) By off, I mean that it doesn't fit into the customary formula of "[greeting] [name]" with _[greeting]_ essentially functioning as a filler in this context.

Comment: In caricatures of public (ie private!) school life, the poor male pupil about to be subjected to slave labour or corporal punishment is often addressed: "**You, boy!**" (That comma signals a modulation rather than a pause, or is perhaps there to distinguish the construction from say "You fiend!")

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In that scenario, it could well be "You, Tom!" too and it tends to also involve some finger-pointing as well. But I don't really think that that applies here. Please see Tyler's theory below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the [prologue](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/76/76-h/76-h.htm) to *The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*.

> IN this book a number of dialects are used, to wit: the Missouri negro dialect; the extremest form of the backwoods Southwestern dialect; the ordinary "Pike County" dialect; and four modified varieties of this last. The shadings have not been done in a haphazard fashion, or by guesswork; but painstakingly, and with the trustworthy guidance and support of personal familiarity with these several forms of speech.
>
> I make this explanation for the reason that without it many readers would suppose that all these characters were trying to talk alike and not succeeding.

Aunt Polly uses the Pike County dialect as does Tom, Huck, and Pap. Among the features of this dialect are the deletion of initial unstressed syllables and the accentuation of stressed vowel sounds. Examples of the former occur in Pap's *'lection* (election) and Huck's *'deed* (indeed). As for the latter, Aunt Polly says *owdacious* (audacious), creating an exaggerated diphthong of the first syllable. She does something similar with *clothes* and *clo'es*, and here Twain accentuates the diphthong in her speech with an apostrophe and the deletion of the "th". The resultant sound of the Pike County dialect is a twangy, drawling thing.

With regards to "Y-o-u-u Tom!" my conjecture is that she is obeying both of the above rules. She is deleting the unstressed syllable--in this case, a whole word: "Hey"--and she is accentuating the stressed vowel, possibly making it a diphthong owing to the second "u" in "Y-o-u-u Tom!". In short,

> *"Hey you, Tom!"*

(I doubt any connection to *yoo-hoo*, which, as has been discussed in [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42352/what-does-yo-ho-ho-mean) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79058/whats-the-origin-of-saying-yoo-hoo-to-get-someones-attention) EL&U post, has more to do with the "pirate" expression *yo-ho* than it does with *you*.)

For an interesting discussion of the accuracy of Twain's claim that only seven spoken dialects occur in Huck Finn, this article by [David Carkeet](http://www.jserra.org/ourpages/auto/2009/9/4/43312140/Dialects%20in%20Huck%20Finn%20Carkeet.pdf) is a good read.

Comment: The proper pronunciation of 'clothes' is ... Well no one actually uses that except maybe an English professor and then only in class...and then only when asked to pronounce it slowly and deliberately. Every other time though it is /klowz/. Pike County isn't special in that regard.

Comment: @Mitch: I imagine it's something like "clow-iz" with two syllables, this owin' to the fact that she also uses *h'yer* (here), which is pronounced in two syllables.

Comment: @Mitch: I would imagine that "clo'es" is unlikely to be pronounced in any way but "clothes" with the 'th' removed, making it sound exactly like the verb "close". In Mark Twain's day, this pronunciation was probably regional and frowned on, whereas today it is extremely widespread. I very much doubt anybody ever said "clo-is".

Comment: @PeterShor, tylerharms: yes, I see. I was only addressing the (currently rarely pronounced) consonant cluster /ðz/. But I'd find it hard to believe that it was ever pronounced fully.

Comment: @Mitch: People pronounce both consonants in *cloths.* Pronouncing both consonants in *clothes* shouldn't be any harder, if you're used to it.

Comment: Thanks for the Huck Finn link, Tyler. Bookmarked :) So what, in your opinion, is Aunt Polly actually saying?

Comment: "Hey you, Tom." As in, *Get over here, Tom. I know'd ya bin playin' hookey!*

Comment: @tylerharms Thanks. Please add that to your answer.

Comment: @tylerharms Actually, I'm not after her _intention_. I'm after what you state is the original "unstressed", "undeleted" version of the sentence sans any additional embellishment.

Comment: @Mitch: Then it'd just be "Hey you, Tom!"

Comment: @Mitch: Let me modify my comment above. Looking at old dictionaries in Google books, it appears that when Mark Twain was writing, in the U.K. people usually dropped the *th* in *clothes,* while in the U.S. *Webster* gives both pronunciations (the one with the *th* first). So the pronunciation without the *th* wasn't frowned upon, but it did mark people's dialects. *Merriam-Webster* now puts the version without the *th* first.

Answer (score -2):

I had rather always imagined it was something more on the order of an older person's frustration with youth.  When one of us was up to something & Papa was upset that was always when he scrambled our names or couldn't seem to get them out at all.  In this regard I thought it was more of a universal human thing than something unique to Pike County speech patterns.  But then as a Southerner, I am perhaps more inclined to view our foibles in a more universal light.  Just my two cents.....

Comment: Please support answers with facts, references, or specific expertise (paraphrasing the [FAQ]). Answers which consist solely of opinion will attract downvotes and may ultimately be deleted.